# Jquery - Salir de una función

Tags: php, html, jquery, html5, jquery-ui

Tengo un evento "click" que hace 2 acciones (paso1 y paso2)
Lo que intento hacer en esta función con **jQuery**, si en el condicional de **title === ""**, salga de la función.
Ahora mismo lo que hace es salir del "each" pero sigue ejecutandose la función.
He probado con return o break (break no me lo reconoce)

```
        $(document).on('click', '#btnSaveForm', function(event) {
        // PASO1
        $('.newClass').each(function(i, items_list) {

            title = $(this).find('.title').val();

            if (title === "") {
                console.log('entro if');
                break;  
            }
        });

        // PASO2
        console.log('LLEGO AL PASO 2');
    });
```

Gracias,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que te ocurre es porque un *return false* lo que hace es salir de la función en la que se encuentra o un *break* lo que hace es salir del bucle en el que se encuentra, y esa función/bucle están definidos sobre el método each, pero el paso 2 está fuera del método, con lo que esa parte del código no se va a ver afectada.

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

- Define una variable fuera del método each:

  ```
    var saltar_paso = false;
  ```
- Dentro de tu método each, si se cumple la condición, setea la variable a *true*

  ```
    if (title === "") {
        saltar_paso = true;
        break;  
    }
  ```
- Al inicio de tu paso dos, pon la condición de que no entre si *saltar_paso* a cambiado a *true*:

  ```
    if(!saltar_paso){
        console.log('LLEGO AL PASO 2');
    }
  ```

Comment: gracias @cooper , así lo he hecho 1000 gracias